# How to improve the query performance of MongoDB in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I run the following query command in mongodb robo command:

```
db.getCollection('t_data').find({"mid":123456,"datetime":{"$gte" : "2016-09-01" , "$lte" : "2016-9-12"}})
```

and it takes about 2 sec to return 10000 records.
howerver,when I put it in java to execute,it takes several minutes to return data (10000 records).there is an index on mid and datetime with {mid:1,datetime:1}.the java code of the query is as follows:

```
    ......
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        DBObject timeObj = new BasicDBObject();
        timeObj.put("$gte", "2016-09-01");
        timeObj.put("$lte", "2016-09-12");
        query.put("mid", 123456);
        query.put("datetime", timeObj);

        DBObject queryField = new BasicDBObject();
        queryField.put("pdid", true);
        queryField.put("data", true);
        queryField.put("datetime", true);

        DBCollection coll = queryService.getCollection('t_data'); 
        DBCursor dbcoursor= coll.find(query,queryField);//only this coding line takes serveral minutes.
        while(dbcoursor.hasNext()) {
                ......
        }

    ......
```

so what is the difference betwwen running in java and mongodb command,the query criteria is same,but the query performance is very different,and how could I improve the query performance in java.

Comment: The possible difference is that your java code very probably fetches these records from mongo, so it generates network traffic. Depending of the complexity/size of your json documents, this can slows you down (of course, it depends what is in your ..... too..

Comment: DBCursor dbcoursor= coll.find(query,queryField); only this coding line takes serveral minutes.

Comment: I found [this](http://farenda.com/mongodb/mongodb-performance-tuning/) page about what could you do. However I think defining the batchSize on your cursor should help.

Comment: "batch size: 
Limits the number of documents returned in one batch. Each batch requires a round trip to the server. It can be adjusted to optimize performance and limit data transfer.

Note batch_size can not override MongoDB’s internal limits on the amount of data it will return to the client in a single batch (i.e if you set batch size to 1,000,000,000, MongoDB will currently only return 4-16MB of results per batch)." Somewhere else I read that the default batch size is 20, so in your case this was about 500 roundtrip...

Comment: To make it harder, [here](http://farenda.com/mongodb/mongodb-performance-tuning/) is another bad news: "Unlike @BatchSize in Hibernate, in MongoDB it is not constant – it is only initial batch size! It sounds at least strange, but the results may cost you a headache, so be warned. For example batch size set to 100 initially returns 99 documents, but subsequent calls can return less and less documents – going even to 30 documents." However, I don't know that this is true or false.

Comment: Btw, do you really need to fetch those documents? If you do some processing (filtering/aggregation) on client side, you can move it (at least partially) to server side by creating [mongodb map/reduce script](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) and you can fetch the result only..

Comment: yes ,I need to fetch all the results to draw the chart.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dbkoda.com/blog/2017/10/01/bulk-operations-in-mongoDB) is a good article about playing around batchSize.

Comment: what is the article？